# If cell is touched - move on the another VC [SWIFT]

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

If cell is touched - move on the another VC, how can i do it?
I tried to do it, but i didn't work.
Here is my code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "transData" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! WinnerViewController

        let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell

        if cell == cell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell!)
            if indexPath == indexPath {
                let productName = users[(indexPath?.row)!]
                destination.winner = productName.name
            }
        }
    }
```

When i touch each cell - it isn't moving.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to perform a segue when a cell is tapped.

1. The segue is connected from the **table view cell** to the destination controller

   In this case the cell is passed as the `sender` parameter

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "transData", let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
            let destination = segue.destination as! WinnerViewController
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!  
            let productName = users[indexPath.row]
            destination.winner = productName.name
       }
   }
   ```
2. The segue is connected from the **source controller** to the destination controller

   In this case you have to implement `didSelectRowAt`, call `performSegue(withIdentifier` and pass the index path as `sender` parameter

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "transData", sender: indexPath)
    }
   ```

   Then `prepare(for` has to be

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "transData", let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
            let destination = segue.destination as! WinnerViewController
            let productName = users[indexPath.row]
            destination.winner = productName.name
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi you can do like this :
take Indexpath as golbal variable eg : var indexPathTemp : IndexPath?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  indexPathTemp = indexPath
  performSegueWithIdentifier("transData", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "transData" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! WinnerViewController
                let productName = users[(indexPath?.row)!]
                destination.winner = productName.name
            }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

The answer from @vadian is detailed and correct. The following are just other ways of navigating from a view controller to another.

If you use `segue`, and want to navigate to the *WinnerViewController*:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER", sender: indexPath)            
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER", let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as? WinnerViewController
            let productName = users[indexPath.row]
            destinationVC.winner = productName.name
        }
    }
```

If you use `Storyboard` and `pushViewController`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let productName = users[indexPath.row]

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR_WINNER_VIEW_IDENTIFIER") as? WinnerViewController else { return}
    destinationVC.winner = productName.name
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
}
```

If you use `Interface Builder` and `pushViewController`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let productName = users[indexPath.row]    
    let destinationVC = WinnerViewController(nibName: "YOUR_WINNER_VIEW_NAME", bundle: nil)
    destinationVC.winner = productName.name
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: No need to `instantiate` anything nor loading nibs when using segues.