# Pass data to text field in UITableViewCell from Another UITableView ( Not using Segue)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 controllers `AddContactController` and `HomepageController`. I want to select each row in the Homepage (which load JSON data from web service). Then pass the data of each row and navigate to `AddContactController` which also `TableViewCell`. How can I do it ? My code is a little bit messy. Any suggestions ?

**AddContactController Class**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId") as! AddContactCell
    let note = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "note") as! Note
    myCell.input_field.delegate = self
    note.input_field.delegate = self as? UITextViewDelegate

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        myCell.nameLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]
        if (myCell.nameLabel.text == "Occupation")
        {
            myCell.input_field.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Occupation",
                                                                   attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(red:0.81, green:0.81, blue:0.83, alpha:1.0)]) 
        }
        else if (myCell.nameLabel.text == "First Name"){
            myCell.input_field.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "First Name",
                                                                          attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(red:0.81, green:0.81, blue:0.83, alpha:1.0)])

        }
        else {
            myCell.input_field.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Last Name",
                                                                          attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(red:0.81, green:0.81, blue:0.83, alpha:1.0)]) 
        }
        myCell.myContactController = self
        return myCell
    }
    else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        myCell.nameLabel.text = "Place"
        myCell.input_field.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Place",
                                                                      attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(red:0.81, green:0.81, blue:0.83, alpha:1.0)])

        return myCell
    }
    else {
        return note
    }
}
```

**Homepagecontroller class**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! RecordCell

    myCell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row
    myCell.playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playAudio(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    myCell.nameLabel.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
    let fullNameArray = nameArray[indexPath.row].components(separatedBy: " ")
    let fname = fullNameArray[0].characters.first
    let lname = fullNameArray[1].characters.first
    var initials: String = ""
    if (fname != nil && lname != nil ) {
        initials.append(fname!)
        initials.append(lname!)
    }
    myCell.shortname.text = initials
    myCell.myTableViewController = self
    return myCell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "InstanceStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! AddContactController
    viewController.
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)    
}
```

**SUPPOSED ALL NEEDED TO PASS DATA IS STORE IN THIS**

`var nameArray = [String]()`

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/44996952/7113238 might help

Comment: Yeah kinda same problem but my problem is that i dont know how to access the table view cell in this case Text Field in the AddContactController FROM Homepage. Maybe create var or something ? @Law

Comment: Why you need to acces textfield of AddContactController from HomePage??

Comment: @luckyShubhra It's a little bit messy but my problem is simple. When I select each row in Homepage. It should push and pass the name of the row to the Text Field in AddContactController for Editing or renaming the contact name for example ? Is that clear for you ? Hope you can help

Comment: You cannot access your cell directly from your HomePage. You can pass data from HomePage to AddContact and reload tableView in didappear or didLoad. After loading you can edit or update data.Check my answer.

Comment: @Van below two answers is doing same job passing selected row value to another controller variable.In second controller use that variable value and get in text field.You can access selected row value in didSelect method from your array ex-: var a = arrayName[indexpath.row] .

Answer (score 1):

To get cell at **selected row** using **indexPath** like that `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)`

SampleCode:

> HomeViewCintroller

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! RecordCell
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "InstanceStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! AddContactController
    viewController.obj = cell.nameLabel.text
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)    
}
```

> AddContactViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.mytxt.text = obj
    return cell
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer but I want to ask that how can I access the viewController.obj (in my case it's a UITextField in UITableViewCell from another Controller)

Comment: Can you explain more.

Comment: @Van do you want to pass text field data from table view cell to second controller?

Comment: @SakirSherasiya So my problem is first I select the row in Homepage. It should push to AddContactController for editing. So I need to pass the name for example into the text field of AddContactController for renaming or something. Is that clear for you guys ?

Comment: So above code for example viewController.obj but my case it's an table view cell ? how can i get it. if it's a label or something I can easily get it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in form of array or dictionary which you received from webservice then declare one object in your HomepageController and then pass your data like this:-

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "InstanceStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! AddContactController
    viewController.details = [some object]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)    }
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that in viewController (Addcontactcontroller) how can I access the table view cell to pass the data from the HomePage

Comment: on that update the array and just call tableView.reloadData

Comment: thank for your answer but I want to ask that how can I access the viewController.obj (in my case it's a UITextField in UITableViewCell from another Controller) @Hussain Shabbir

Comment: If I understand it correctly then you cannot directly access the tableviewcell unless it is loaded. What you can do is pass data into another controller and when its loaded refresh the table and populate data from your datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You cant access another class UITableViewClass from your current class. your TableView gets instantianted once your AddContactViewController is loaded. You can cannot access AddContactViewController subviews before it gets instantiated. You can pass required data as described by @Sakhir and @hussain in array or dictionary format. And reload your tableview in viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad of AddContactViewController. You can set your data in your textField in `cellforRowAtIndexPath` as `textfield.text = yourValue`. After loading you can edit or update data.Hope you get it.